# float object is not callable

Tags: python, numpy

I have multiple for-loops inside a while loop in my Python code. For the first iteration, everything works fine. For the second iteration of the while-loop, I get the following error:

```
File ".\simulated_annealing.py", line 209, in <module>
 for ii in range(0, 8, 1) :
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

Below is the relevant piece of my code:

```
while numpy.absolute(FcostOld) >= 0.001 and l <= L :

    Fx = []
    Fy = []
    Fz = []
    V = []
    ii = 0  

    for ii in range(0, 8, 1) :          # ... LINE 209
        Fx.append([])
        Fy.append([])
        Fz.append([])
        for j in range(0, 13, 1) :
            Fx[ii].append(0)
            Fy[ii].append(0)
            Fz[ii].append(0)
        V.append(0.0)   

    print "\n l = ", l
    j = 0
    print "j = ", j
    i = 0
    for i in range(0, 8) :
        print "i = ", i
        """
        V[i] = 0.0
        for j in range(0, 13, 1) :
            Fx[i][j] = 0.0
            Fy[i][j] = 0.0
            Fz[i][j] = 0.0
        """

        for j in range(0, 6, 1) :
            for k in range(0, Natoms, 1) :
                dxxC = x[i][j] - Layer15[k][0]
                dyyC = y[i][j] - Layer15[k][1]
                dzzC = zC - Layer15[k][2]
                rrC = numpy.sqrt(dxxC*dxxC + dyyC*dyyC + dzzC*dzzC)
                
                if rrC <= rcut :
                    V[i] = V[i] + VrealC(rrC, DeC, alphaC, rC, s6)
                    Fx[i][j] = Fx[i][j] + frealC(rrC, DeC, alphaC, rC, dxxC, s6)
                    Fy[i][j] = Fy[i][j] + frealC(rrC, DeC, alphaC, rC, dyyC, s6)
                    Fz[i][j] = Fz[i][j] + frealC(rrC, DeC, alphaC, rC, dzzC, s6)

        for j in range(6, 12, 1) :
            for k in range(0, Natoms, 1) :
                dxxH = x[i][j] - Layer15[k][0]
                dyyH = y[i][j] - Layer15[k][1]
                dzzH = zH - Layer15[k][2]
                rrH = numpy.sqrt(dxxH*dxxH + dyyH*dyyH +dzzH*dzzH)
                
                if rrH <= rcut :
                    V[i] = V[i] + VrealH(rrH, DeH, alphaH, rH, s6)
                    Fx[i][j] = Fx[i][j] + frealH(rrH, DeH, alphaH, rH, dxxH, s6)
                    Fy[i][j] = Fy[i][j] + frealH(rrH, DeH, alphaH, rH, dyyH, s6)
                    Fz[i][j] = Fz[i][j] + frealH(rrH, DeH, alphaH, rH, dzzH, s6)

        j = 12
        for k in range(0, Natoms, 1) :
            dxxX = x[i][j] - Layer15[k][0]
            dyyX = y[i][j] - Layer15[k][1]
            dzzX = zX - Layer15[k][2]
            rrX = numpy.sqrt(dxxX*dxxX + dyyX*dyyX +dzzX*dzzX)
                
            if rrX <= rcutX :
                V[i] = V[i] + VrealX(rrH, DeH, alphaH, rH, s6)
                Fx[i][j] = Fx[i][j] + frealX(rrX, DeX, alphaX, rX, dxxX, s6)
                Fy[i][j] = Fy[i][j] + frealX(rrX, DeX, alphaX, rX, dyyX, s6)
                Fz[i][j] = Fz[i][j] + frealX(rrX, DeX, alphaX, rX, dzzX, s6)        
        
        print "i = ", i

    if flag == False :
        FcostOld_V = 0 * numpy.sqrt( sum(numpy.power(V[n]-VTarget[n], 2) for n in range(0,8)) ) / numpy.sqrt( sum((V[n]*V[n]) for n in range(0,8)) )
        FcostOld_F = numpy.absolute( sum(Fz[n][m] for n in range(0,8) for m in range(0,13)) ) / 8
        FcostOld = FcostOld_V + FcostOld_F   
    
    if flag == True :
        FcostNew_V = 0 * numpy.sqrt( sum(numpy.power(V[n]-VTarget[n], 2) for n in range(0,8)) ) / numpy.sqrt( sum((V[n]*V[n]) for n in range(0,8)) )
        FcostNew_F = numpy.absolute( sum(Fz[n][m] for n in range(0,8) for m in range(0,13)) ) / 8
        FcostNew = FcostNew_V + FcostNew_F      

        if (FcostNew - FcostOld) < 0:
            s6Old = s6
            FcostOld = FcostNew
            DeCOld = DeC
            alphaCOld = alphaC
            rCOld = rC
            DeHOld = DeH
            alphaHOld = alphaH
            rHOld = rH
            DeXOld = DeX
            alphaXOld = alphaX
            rXOld = rX
    
        if (FcostNew - FcostOld) >= 0 :
            P = numpy.exp( -(FcostNew-FcostOld) / kT )
            r0 = numpy.random.rand()
            if r0 < P :
                s6Old = s6
                FcostOld = FcostNew
                DeCOld = DeC
                alphaCOld = alphaC
                rCOld = rC
                DeHOld = DeH
                alphaHOld = alphaH
                rHOld = rH
                DeXOld = DeX
                alphaXOld = alphaX
                rXOld = rX

    flag = True
            

    range = 0.1

    DeC = NewParameter(DeCOld, range)       
    alphaC = NewParameter(alphaCOld, 2*range)       
    rC = NewParameter(rC, range/2)

    DeH = NewParameter(DeHOld, 5*range)     
    alphaH = NewParameter(alphaHOld, 2*range)       
    rH = NewParameter(rH, range/3)

    DeX = NewParameter(DeXOld, range)       
    alphaX = NewParameter(alphaXOld, 2*range)       
    rX = NewParameter(rX, range/2)

    s6 = NewParameter(s6Old, range)

    if numpy.mod(l,1) == 0 : 
        print "\nFcost = ", FcostOld
        print Fx[7]

    print " l = ", l
    l = l + 1
```

Comment: `range(0, 8, 1)` is equivalent to `range(8)`.  You can omit the 0 and the 1.

Comment: Please, for your own sanity - use descriptive variable names.

Answer (score 14):

Don't use `range` as a variable name. It shadows builtin function`range`:

```
>>> range = 0.1
>>> range(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 5):

`range` is a builtin that returns a list of values to iterate over.  On line 317 you have `range = 0.1`, which is replacing the builtin `range` function with a `float` value.

The second time through the loop, instead of using the normal `range` function, your program instead sees a float, this will be like saying `for ii in 0.1(0, 8, 1):` which obviously doesn't make sense.

To fix this, just use a different variable name than `range` such as `interval = 0.1`.

The error message you are receiving comes from you trying to *call* a float.

```
>>> x = 1.1
>>> x()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

the `()` are used for function calls.  Since `x` is a `float` in the above example, it fails because you can't call a `float`.